# XML file after debugging not updating

Tags: c#, xml

I have a c# project which I added a xml-file (Add -> New -> xml).

The property of the file for `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Copy if newer` and in the project properties for `Publish` -> `Application Files` -> `Publish Status` is set to `Include`.

When I debug my project I read and write that xml-file and it is correct updating in the `bin/Debug` folder but not in the main folder of the solution. So the xml-file in the solution is not updated, only the xml-file in the `Debug` folder.

I know from other projects that I get a hint when I stop debugging after a xml-file was modified that the xml-file was updated and if I want to reload it. That hint I don't get so something must be wrong with the link to that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rewrite the XML file that is part of your project, you have to write to that XML file - not to the copy in your bin\debug folder.  This is not generally what most people want. If the file is part of your project, most people would consider that a source file that you would want to keep in its original condition, not a file that you want to edit while debugging.

If that is what you want to accomplish, make sure you read and write to ..\..\MyFile.xml relative to your executable.  That's assuming the XML file is in the root folder of your project, and that your project isn't configured to use any non-standard folder structure.

Comment: Or alternatively put the xml file somewhere on your c drive (program data/<app name> for example) where it can be edited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but maybe you missunderstood me. I write directly in the xml of the project, not to the copy in the debug folder (`dsTemp.WriteXml("AppData/Test.xml");`. But this xml in the project folder is not updating, only the one for debuging in the debug folder.

Comment: Unless you've set the working folder elsewhere, "AppData/Test.xml" is a path relative to your executable.  In other words, since your executable is at (projectfolder)\bin\debug, the path resolves to (projectfolder)\bin\debug\AppData\Test.xml"  Try writing to ..\..\AppData\Test.xml, which would be (projectfolder)\Appdata\Test.xml.